# Why does jailbreaking causes many errors in ios devices?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, crash, tweaks

I have an iPad Air running ios 7.1.2, the device is great it runs smoothly without any lags or errors, some apps crashes only a few times. But when I jailbroken the device, the cydia apps where crashing 80 percent of the time, sometimes they disappeared and would reappear after a device restart. The iPad would sometimes freeze when I open cydia store. With this in mind, although jailbreaking gives you a lot of advantages, after all these problems it doesn't seem worth jailbreaking my device. Can someone tell me why these problems happens and is their a way to solve them?

Comment: The instability is probably caused by 2 incompatible tweaks. Could you give us a list of your installed Cydia tweaks/apps?

Answer (score -1):

If you know about jailbreaking you really should know what it does. It is literally changing how the OS operates, disables some functions and replaces them with others. "Hacking" in the classic sense of modifying someone else's design. None of this has been approved by Apple, nor tested by Apple, nor anyone who writes apps. When you jailbreak a device, even Android phone or any other electronic equipment (computer, cable box, old ham radio, electric toothbrush), you run the risk of it not working right (at least not how it came from the factory).

Though the jailbreak community is extremely talented, they can never guarantee everything will work perfectly. They can't. Apple can change the OS so it disables jailbreaks, either by will or by accident.

The solution is to either: A- don't jailbreak or B- jailbreak and live with some issues like yours that crop up. This is my philosophical answer. If, as Kymer suggests, there is simply some app conflict, that still falls under solution "B" -living with it but trying to troubleshoot and deal with those kind of issues (that's my more pragmatic answer).

Comment: This is full of misinformation, oversimplifications, errors and doesn't address the question at hand.

Comment: The OP's question didn't give enough detail for a technical analysis. It's vague and sounded more like a general complaint against jailbreaking. If you can actually solve the problem, be my guest.